# suggestion of methods(java) in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

Assume I have Button b. I want that when I type "b." , Eclipse will offer me Button's method.
How can I do it? I don't find it in Java > Editor .

Thanks!

Comment: It's the default behavior. Youmight have disabled it, though. What happend when you enter `b.` then type Ctrl-Space?

Comment: Ensure the class Button has already been imported. Eclipse needs it to know which methods are available.

Comment: Ctrl-Space on b. :  "no default proposal".
and yes , it is already import

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that your `Button` is imported in the source code.

Go to **Preferences** -> **Java** -> **Editor** -> **Content Assist** -> **Enable auto activation** with a **200 ms** delay and **dot** (.) as activation trigger.

From **Content Assist**, go to **Advanced** and Restore Defaults, press OK.